# Buttons between tbodies in html table?

Tags: html, button, html-table

I have an `html` table with two `tbodies`. I want to place a set of `buttons` between the `tbodies`.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

If I do it, they appear at the very top of the table.

Comment: Just add a third tbody with one single row and one (spanned) cell. There you'll put your buttons. Well, I wouldn't use table layout for that but...

Comment: What did you tried? please add some code you tried

Comment: Adriano, yes, that is a good answer, please write it as a answer and I'll accept it.